# Custom font is not working in TailwindCSS & ReactJS project

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fonts, next.js, tailwind-css

I am using custom font in my React/TypeScript/TailWind/NextJS projects.
I stored font in my `/fonts` folder as `Glimer-Regular.ttf`.

Then in my `global.css` I declared as below.

```
@layer base {

    @font-face {
        font-family: '"Glimer"';
        src: url(../../fonts/Glimer-Regular.ttf) format('ttf');
    }
}
```

In my `tailwind.config.js` file, I added font family as below.

```
module.exports = {
    mode: 'jit',
    important: true,

    purge: ['./src/pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
    darkMode: false,
    content: [],
    theme: {
        extend: {
            fontFamily: {
                glimer: ['"Glimer"']
            },
```

This should work but the font is still default and showing `serif-400`. I still can see `Glimer` in family section but the font seems like not changed.
Is there anything I am missing?
[image]

Comment: You have double quotes around font family name. Any possibility this is the problem? `font-family: '"Glimer"';`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I created this example with two different fonts..I hope You will Enjoy It ;-)! First, download the `fonts` you want to the `font` folder in Your project directory, below is the structure of the project's files and folders. This is my solution proposition:

**example.js**

```
function ExamplePage() {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center h-screen gap-3">
      <h3 className="text-3xl font-custom1 text-blue-600">
        Sic Parvis Magna..
      </h3>
      <h3 className="text-3xl font-custom1 text-red-600">
        Per aspera ad astra..
      </h3>
      <h3 className="text-2xl font-custom2">
        In vino veritas, in aqua sanitas..
      </h3>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ExamplePage;
```

---

**tailwind.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    fontFamily: {
      custom1: ["Custom-1", "sans-serif"],
      custom2: ["Custom-2", "sans-serif"],
    },

    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

---

**globals.css**

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@font-face {
  font-family: "Custom-1";
  src: url("/font/NewTegomin-Regular.ttf");
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Custom-2";
  src: url("/font/Nosifer-Regular.ttf");
}
```

---

Project **Folder & File** structure:

[image]

---

**Output**:

[image]

**Output** small screen iPhone SE 2022 safari:

[image]

---

*Tested with: "next": "12.0.7", "react": "17.0.2", "tailwindcss": "^3.0.5"*

Comment: So basically there are two methods; 1) Global 2) Use as needed? I wish the folks at `TailwindCSS` would make this clearer in their documentation. Thanks @MarioG8.

Comment: And if you want to apply the font family to whole body you can use on your index.css or global.css like this : body{
    @apply font-FONT_NAME;
}