# How to add my local fonts in tailwind, using reactjs? (solved)

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

**Solved - using fonts cannot use with another alphabet (Ukrainian)**

I tried different variant to add my local fonts to the project. But nothing worked for me.

File structure is:
main_folder

- node_module
- public
- src
  | font (folder)
  | App.css
  | App.js
  | index.css
  | index.js
- tailwind.config.js

My App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="font-sans">
      <h1 className="text-4xl font-custom1">Block 1</h1>
      <h1 className="text-4xl font-custom2">Block 2</h1> 
    </div>
     
  );
}

export default App;
```

My tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./src/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        custom1: ["Сustom1", "sans-serif"],
        custom2: ["Сustom2", "sans-serif"],
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

My index.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer base {
  @font-face {
    font-family: "Custom1";
    src: url("./font/Gilmer Regular.otf");
  }

  @font-face {
    font-family: "Custom2";
    src: url("./font/Salsa-Regular.ttf");
  }
}
```

I tried all this article but without any result.

[tailwind use font from local files globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60854215/tailwind-use-font-from-local-files-globally)
[Custom font is not working in TailwindCSS & ReactJS project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70575038/custom-font-is-not-working-in-tailwindcss-reactjs-project)
[Custom @font-face Tailwind - font isn't displaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74973847/custom-font-face-tailwind-font-isnt-displaying)

Comment: so other tailwind styles work just the fonts don't?

Comment: in index.css have you tried removing the @layer base from wrapping the @font-face? that works for me.

Comment: Yes, I checked box-border, text (like in my example), bg-color

Comment: I removed the @layer, but doesn't work.

Comment: can you post how the index.css looks after you removed it? because that worked for me

Comment: also i just realized you posted that the folder name is 'fonts' and in you index.css you have 'font' as the folder name

Comment: https://ibb.co/27GGy1R

Comment: Sorry, it's my printing error. In my project I have folder 'font'

Comment: I edited mistake.

Comment: try adding url("./font/Gilmer Regular.otf") format("opentype"); and url("./font/Salsa-Regular.ttf") format("truetype")

Comment: .ttf font starts working after I changed format from ttf to truetype.

Comment: ok 50% there. in the screenshot there is a '\' in the path is that a mistake?

Comment: VS Code use '\' to describe spacing between words. I changed name of font (Gilmer-Regular.otf now).

Comment: not sure why it wouldnt work. update your question to show everything that changed and what is and is not working so someone else can help

Comment: The first font was broken then I started using another language (Ukrainian).  https://ibb.co/87CgjGj
https://ibb.co/sFN2sFp

Comment: Maybe I should to change format to UTF-8?

Comment: im not sure what you mean.  can you please explain your question now?

Comment: Nevermind. I found the problem. When using another alphabet, letters use to 'sans' font but english alphabet use new that  I chose.
https://ibb.co/YXBKQJ6